# Deleting the zip files from an external folder having 2 year old using SAS

Tags: sas

Iam trying with the below code and I could able to delete the files which is in zip format but I need to know how we can filter to delete only the 2 year old files . The file name will be SFRE_BIL_SIT_20160812_134317_PAM_FILES1.zip
when doing the filtering for deleting the 2 year old fiIes I  need to concentrate only the year and month part for the file to do the deletion because the day part would be changing  . Please find below the code

```
options mlogic;
%macro delete_all_zip_files_in_folder(folder);
   filename filelist "&folder";
   data _null_;
      dir_id = dopen('filelist');
      total_members = dnum(dir_id);
      do i = 1 to total_members;  
         member_name = dread(dir_id,i);
         if scan(lowcase(member_name),2,'.')='zip' then do; 
          file_id = mopen(dir_id,member_name,'i',0);
          if file_id > 0 then do; 
            freadrc = fread(file_id);
            rc = fclose(file_id);
            rc = filename('delete',member_name,,,'filelist');
            rc = fdelete('delete');
         end;
         rc = fclose(file_id);
      end;
      end;
      rc = dclose(dir_id);
   run;
%mend;


%delete_all_zip_files_in_folder(C:\Users\UCS1MKP\Desktop\test)
```

Comment: Is it always 3 part code before date `SFRE_BIL_SIT_YYYYMMDD` or it varies?
Why are you doing `mopen` and `fread`?

Comment: Does that code run?  How does it not do what you want?

Comment: Yes before date is is always 3 part code and the date will be yyyymmdd . its better we can concentrate only on the year and month from this field because we may not know which day in a month the files will generate. The code which i wrote is running but it deleting all zip files. mopen usng to open the directory and fread reads the files. Now I need  to change this code such a way that it should delete the files which older 12 months

Answer (score 0):

If your files are named in the same manner - 3 part code then date, all separated with `_` you can use `scan()`. You allready used `scan()` to check for files with `zip` extension. You can do the same to extract date part from file name and then parse it and convert to numbers.

## Solution 1

Fourth word of `member_name` is YYYYMMDD part:

`datestring = scan(member_name,4,'_')`

First 4 digits are year:

`year = input(substr(datestring,1,4),best.)`

Then 2 digits for month:

`month = input(substr(datestring,5,2),best.)`

Finally 2 digits for day (just in case you will need day):

`day = input(substr(datestring,5,2),best.)`

At the end just compare with actual month and year:

```
if month = month(today()) and year = year(today()) then do;
    *your code for deleting file;
end;
```

But t will work only for given month. To make it delete files older than 2 years you can do something like below.

## Solution 2

Allready having all date parts construct date:

`date = mdy(month, day, year)`

Then compare it with actual date minus 2 years. To shift date exacly 2 years from today you should use `intnx()` function

```
if intnx('year', today(), -2, 'S') > date do;
    *your code for deleting file;
end;
```

Comment: @ fl0r3k  Hi I used the beow code and my code for deleting the files but its not working    `month = input(substr(datestring,5,2),best.);
  day = input(substr(datestring,7,2),best.);
  year = input(substr(datestring,1,4),best.);
  date = mdy(month, day, year);
    if intnx('year', today(),-2) > date then do;`

Comment: @Manesh What part of this code is not working? There can be only one thing that doesn't work. In `INTNX()` function there is 4th parameter saying if shift should be to beginning, ending, middle or same date. Allready corrected it in my answear.

Comment: @ fl0r3k  Hi Thanks for your suggestions. I used the same and now I could delete the files. Thank ...